# How to disable google cloud endpoints user auth?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I am using my custom auth flow (auth using facebook) and want to completely disable authentication provided by Google Cloud Endpoints.

When I set it using the HTTP Authorization header(Bearer ) it invokes some framework method automatically, which shows following entries in logs-

`D 2015-03-21 20:41:22.622 Checking for id_token.
D 2015-03-21 20:41:22.622 id_token verification failed: Token is not an id_token (Wrong number of segments)
D 2015-03-21 20:41:22.623 Checking for oauth token.
D 2015-03-21 20:41:22.627 Oauth framework user didn't match oauth token user.`

I think its calling google apis and checking the oauth token everytime.

I tried setting `auth_level=endpoints.AUTH_LEVEL.REQUIRED` but the warning is still there.

Finally, I went through the source code to debug this and set env variable `ENDPOINTS_USE_OAUTH_SCOPE` to some random value to prevent it from checking with google api's.

Is there a better way to handle this?

[EDIT] This is for AppEngine Python.

Comment: If you post your code, someone will be more likely able to help you.

Comment: Google Cloud Endpoints is designed to work specifically with Google Accounts or Google+ Signin. If you want to use your own auth scheme you would be better off using a different framework such as Restlet, Spring, or Jersey.

Comment: I disagree with @Adam , you **can** build your own auth implementation using endpoints, it's not as straighforward as using the builtin OAuth but it's pretty easy.

Comment: I am using python. The reason I opted for endpoints was its ability to automatically generate client sdks, manage versioning swiftly. The tight coupling with Google Accounts is sad.
I am using my own auth, but the warning messages which suggest its hitting google api's are of concern.

Comment: Is this question better suited to be sent to appengine google group mailing-list?

Comment: @jirungaray Could you please add more information how to implement this using Java e.g. link to tutorial, article or sample code

Comment: @tomrozb im adding an "answer" so i can explain a little further

Answer (score 1):

As requested by @tomrozb , here's a very simple implementation we are using today. There's really not much to it.

First our AngularJS frontend attaches a header token to **every** request, this token is aquired on login (non authenticated endpoint) and stored locally (pretty similar to a cookie) . Make sure to HTTPS!

On my endpoints i just check for that token using  `req.getHeader("Authorization");` and check that token against my current "sessions" and throw an `UnauthorizedException("Not logged in")` exception. Bear in mind the original HTTPServletRequest is automatically injected if requested so you can do something like:

```
@ApiMethod(name="createWhatever", path="createWhatever")
public Whatever createWhatever(CreateWhateverRequest data, HttpServletRequest req) throws UnauthorizedException{

Long userId = getUserId(req.getHeader("Authorization"));
    if(userId == null){
            throw new UnauthorizedException("Not logged in");
        }
//do your thing
}
```

Which is basically what the builtin feature does,it injects a "User" object on your request and asks you to check if its null and act accordingly, i just do it against a custom entity instead of whatever GAE credentials stores for OAuth.